# Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to two 'CGFloat' operands

Tags: 3d, swift3, pow

I'm writing 3D game and trying to write expression in the handler of the extracted taps:

```
  override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent!) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let touchPoint: CGPoint  = touch.location(in: self)

         if (isTracking == true && sqrtf(powf((touchPoint.x - thumbNode.position.x), 2) + powf((touchPoint.y - thumbNode.position.y), 2)) < size * 2)
        {...}
     }
  }
```

But Xcode wrote error:

**Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to two 'CGFloat' operands.**

Than tried:

```
 var arg_3 = (touchPoint.x - self.anchorPointInPoints().x)
 var expr_3 = powf(Float(arg_3), 2)
 var arg_4 = (touchPoint.y - self.anchorPointInPoints().y)
 var expr_4 = powf(Float(arg_4),2)
 var expr_5 = expr_3 + expr_4
 var expr_6 = thumbNode.size.width

 if (sqrtf(Float(expr_5)) <= expr_6)
 {}
```

Now it wrotes:

**Binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Float' and 'CGFloat'**

Please help me to fix that problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has something for you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670378/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-cgfloat-operands

Comment: Thanks. I've read this topic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a missleading (wrong) error message.

`powf` does not accept `CGFloat`s as parameters.

Create a `Float` instead:

```
let x = Float(touchPoint.x - thumbNode.position.x)
powf(x, 2)
```

---

EDIT:

Solution approach 1:

```
let y = Float(touchPoint.y - thumbNode.position.y)
let x = Float(touchPoint.x - thumbNode.position.x)
if (isTracking == true && sqrtf(powf(x, 2) + powf(y, 2)) < size * 2)
    {...}
```

Solution approach 2:

```
if (sqrtf(Float(expr_5)) <= Float(expr_6)) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for idea, but it's doesn't works. Binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Float' and 'CGFloat'

Comment: My answer did not mention your second approach (`<=`) but the first. See updated answer. But the solution is the same. You should use some brain too :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pow` and `sqrt` which take and return `CGFloat`, which is the type of the values in your `CGPoint`. This avoids the use of any casts in your sample as everything will be `CGFloat`.